# Rewriting Eigen code into OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I have code written in C++ that is using Eigen and I need to rewrite it in OpenCV. The problem is that I haven't used Eigen before and I can't find any more extensive examples to help me out.

This is a code sample:

```
int n;
Eigen::VectorXd alpha;
Eigen::MatrixXd L;
alpha = L.topLeftCorner(n, n).triangularView<Eigen::Lower>().solve(y);
L.topLeftCorner(n, n).triangularView<Eigen::Lower>().adjoint().solveInPlace(alpha);
```

The values of `n`, `L` and `y` are set earlier in the code.

Could someone please help me figure out what exactly is happening in this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L is an n x n lower triangular matrix.

alpha is the solution of the linear system L * alpha = y.

alpha is then recomputed in-place as the solution of the linear system
[adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)(L) * x = alpha.